# On Spec($K\otimes_k k^{p^{-\infty}}$)

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0$.
Let $K$ be an extension field of $k$.
Let $k^{p^{-\infty}}$ be the perfect closure of $k$.
Then Spec($K\otimes_k k^{p^{-\infty}}$) is a one element set?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29935/question-about-tensor-of-two-fields

Comment: @YACP Thanks. As for the Mariano's answer, I don't have the Jacobson's book at hand.
As for the Georges' answer, I think it's a bit overkill, though the Grothendieck's formula is interesting.
I like the Robin Chapman's answer most.
I don't know why he got only one upvote.

Comment: @Makoto Kato: Robin obviously didn't get more than one upvote because people like you didn't upvote him...

Comment: I could not log in MathOverflow at that time so I could not upvote for Robin Chapman.
I have no idea why my comment saying so was removed by a moderator. By the way, I already upvoted for him.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = K\otimes_k k^{p^{-\infty}}$.
We identify $K$ with its canonical image in $A$.
Let $P$ and $Q$ be prime ideals of $A$.
It suffices to prove that $P \subset Q$.
Let $\pi\colon A \rightarrow A/P$ be the canonical homomorphism.
Let $\sigma\colon K \rightarrow A/P$ be the restriction of $\pi$.
Let $x \in P$.
It suffices to prove that $x \in Q$.
$x$ can be written as $x = \sum_{i} x_i \otimes y_i$, where $x_i \in K$ and $y_i \in k^{p^{-\infty}}$.
There exists an integer $n \gt 0$ such that $y_i^{p^n} \in k$ for all $i$.
Then $x^{p^n} = \sum_{i} x_i^{p^n} \otimes y_i^{p^n} = \sum_{i} x_i^{p^n}y_i^{p^n} \otimes 1$.
Since $x^{p^n} \in P$, $\pi(x^{p^n}) = \sum_{i} \sigma(\sum_{i} x_i^{p^n}y_i^{p^n}) = 0$.
Hence $\sum_{i} x_i^{p^n}y_i^{p^n} = 0$.
Hence $x^{p^n} = 0$.
Hence $x^{p^n} \in Q$.
Since $Q$ is prime, $x \in Q$ as desired.
**QED**